# Allowing  a form field input to echo a variable?

Tags: php, html

Long story short, I want users to be able to call the value of the variable `$city_name` into a string that they will submit.

Here's my code;

```
<?php

if(!isset($post_text)) {
$city_name = "Dallas";
$post_text = $_POST['post_text'];
echo($post_text);
}

?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="post_text" type="text" value="enter text here" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I was under the impression that calling `$city_name` in the form field `post_text` would return "Dallas", unfortunately that's not the case.

If anyone has any advice or information on what alterations I could add to this code in order to allow the user to call the value of `$city_name`, it would be greatly appreciated :)!!

Comment: Can you please restate your question? You do not "call" variables/values, "call" is a synonym for run/invoke/execute, and is used to describe running/invoking/executing a function, method or other block of code. We have here some PHP code, and a form. How do you intend for them to interact?

Comment: Do you want "Dallas" to appear somewhere on the form? Do you want to do something with "Dallas" after a form is submitted? You say "calling city_name in the form post_text", but I can't figure out what you are saying is "calling" since you never mingle these two variables in any way (you don't assign one to the other, you don't concatenate them together, you don't put either into the HTML of the form...). What we have is a variable named `$city_name` containing the word Dallas, and a variable named `$post_text` containing whatever was in the form input `post_text` when that form was submitted.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure what the most appropriate term is that case. I would like for the user to be able to input and submit a string such as `I am going to $city_name` and have `I am going to Dallas` echoed on submit.

Comment: Still a little confusing -- do you want it to return "Dallas" every time, or just reflect whatever the user has input? (So, if I input "Boston", will it say "I am going to Boston" or "I am going to Dallas"?)

Comment: I have posted how you would do that. It is by no means automatic.

Comment: No Dallas is merely a placeholder, I want it to echo the value of $city_name, whatever that value is, whereas now it only echoes `$city_name` instead of it's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I would like for the user to be able to input and submit a string such as "I am going to $city_name" and have "I am going to Dallas" echoed on submit.

This is the code:

```
$city_name = "Dallas";
$post_text = str_replace('$city_name', $city_name, $_POST['post_text']);
echo $post_text;
```

It's important to use single quotes around `'$city_name'` here as you are searching for the literal text `$city_name` and not the contents of the variable `$city_name`.